# Capture video for a certain time then quit and save to a folder using OpenCV 3

Tags: raspbian, python, opencv

I am using this sample code from the OpenCV documentation and what the code is simply doing is capturing a video and when it's interrupted it saves it to a folder.

What I want to do it capture the video for a certain period of time, quit, and then save it to the folder and I really don't know how to do it.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)

        # write the flipped frame
        out.write(frame)

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps:

1. Get the start time with `startTime = time.time()`
2. Get the time elapsed in **seconds** with `timeElapsed = startTime - time.time()`
3. Remove the decimal places with `secElapsed = int(timeElapsed)`
4. Stop the program after x seconds `while(secElapsed < 100)`

---

If you you need further help you will find this code useful:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

# Define the duration (in seconds) of the video capture here
capture_duration = 10

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

start_time = time.time()
while( int(time.time() - start_time) < capture_duration ):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)

        # write the flipped frame
        out.write(frame)

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        #if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        #    break
    else:
        break

# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```